# Predefined Classes in Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using `Ant Design` in my React project but did not totally understand how it works. Does Ant Design have predefined classes like Bootstrap? For example, if I wanted to center elements in Bootstrap I would do something like that?

```
class="d-flex justify-content-center"
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes Antd have predefined classes like bootstrap

If you want to center element use  **justify="center"** It will work only on Row

but you can customize the antd  element by using @emotion/styled package.

You need to inspect the button and get the button class from the element tab

[image]

Now you need to create a custom style for the button

Step 1: you need to import @emotion/styled

import Styled from "@emotion/styled";

Step 2 : Now Override the CSS of the Button

```
const CustomButton = Styled(Button)`
.ant-btn-primary{
 background-color: #4BA461;
}
`
```

Step 3 Now use this CustomButton where you want like

```
 <CustomButton>Register</CustomButton>
```

Installation Process

> > npm install --save @emotion/styled

```
 or
```

> > yarn add @emotion/styled

You can learn more about emotion/styled from https://emotion.sh/docs/install

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here in `Ant Design` CSS properties are applied in attributes like `center='sm'` and In bootstrap, CSS properties are applied in classes like `justify-content-sm-center`.

please follow this URL https://ant.design/components/grid/#API

Comment: don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!